# Replacing <img> tags with links to their content jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title says, I am having some issues converting images to links using jquery. My code right now is:

```
var all_img =  $(".message .content").find("img");

$.each(all_img, function (index, value) {
    var src = value.src;
    value.replaceWith($("<a href='" + src +"'>Image  " + index+1 + "</a>"));
});
```

Which results in the images being replaced with `[object Object]`. I have also tried:

```
$.each(all_img, function (index, value) {
    var src = value.src;
    value.replaceWith("<a href='" + src +"'>Image  " + index+1 + "</a>");
});
```

Which results in the html I am trying to insert going in as plain unclickable text. Am I misunderstanding how `.replaceWith()` works?

Comment: Post your HTML as well please. We like a [mcve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You couldn't call the jQuery `.replaceWith()` method on `value`, you need to use a jQuery object, to target the current img in every iteration you need to use  `$(this)` like :

```
all_img.each(function (index, value) {
    var src = value.src;
    $(this).replaceWith("<a href='" + src +"'>Image  " + index+1 + "</a>");
});
```

Comment: Or you could also `$(value).replaceWith(...);`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to create a new element and remove/hide the img:

```js
$('.turnInAnchor').click(function(e){
  $('img').each(function(index, el) {
     $('body')
    .append("<a href='"+el.src+"' target='_blank'>Image "+index+"</a>");
    el.remove();

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="turnInAnchor">Turn in anchor</button>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/7/75/Twin_Peaks_Episodio_Pilota_Laura_Palmer.png" />
```